# JIRA Usage on AWS

Tags: url, tomcat, amazon-web-services, jira

I just set up JIRA on my ec2 instance after installing it via .bin installer file. But when I hit the ec2 url:

```
ec2-xxxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com
```

It is hitting the test success page for apache2 which I installed after JIRA installation.

How do I get to determine the correct URL for JIRA and hit the JIRA app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JIRA defaut http port is 8080. So you need access it via

```
ec2-xxxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com:8080
```

if you are not following the detault setting, then you need make sure which port are set by this document [Changing JIRA's TCP Ports](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Changing+JIRA's+TCP+Ports)

You may need open the firewall port 8080 and set in one security group which you assign port 22 to be opened. Otherwise, you can't directly access that port.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the previous answer you may wish to ensure the following:

1. Your AWS EC2 Instance security group have the port opened
2. Your AWS VPC ACL allows TCP traffic on this port
3. Your VPC have an internet gateway
4. Your VPC have the routes configured
5. Your Apache proxy is configured to point to the Tomcat port
6. Your Tomcat is configured
7. You have enabled port allocation using setcap utility
8. Your local machine firewall enables the connection (in Red Hat ipconfig is enabled by default and blocks the connections)

As you can see it may be tricky to install Jira on AWS. It may be a good idea to use a deployment service like Deploy4Me to do this quickly.